# If Processor=xx-bit do this in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch script to execute a certain program depending on the architecture of the system. For example, something like this:

```
If ProcessorArch=64-bit 7zip64.exe
If ProcessorArch=32-bit 7zip.exe
If ProcessorArch=x86-64-bit 7zipx86-64.exe
```

Thank you

Comment: The data you're looking for is located in `wmic os`. The output of a command can be processed with a `for /f` loop. That's all the help I can give you until you edit your question to include code you have written.

Comment: @SomethingDark Thank you for the suggestion. The part that says "If ProcessorArch....." is my code.

Comment: If the value of `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` always include a `64` in these cases, this should work: `if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:64=%" equ "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" (echo Is 32-bit) else echo Is 64-bit`

Comment: @Aacini Hey! Thanks! This works pretty good! I just have one question. Is it possible for it to do this too?
`if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:86-64=%" equ "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" echo Is 32/64-bit`

Comment: Note that in my example I am _removing_ the `64` string from `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` variable, so if the result is **equal**, it means that the `64` does _**NOT**_ appear in the variable! In your example you should use `neq` comparison to indicate that the `86-64` part DO appear in the variable.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of environment variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`

1. is always **x86** on running 32-bit Windows independent on architecture of the CPU as even on a motherboard with an Intel/AMD x64 processor a 32-bit Windows can be installed and running instead of Windows x64 and
2. is either **x86** or **AMD64** or **IA64** on running 64-bit Windows depending on

   - architecture of CPU and running Windows: **AMD64** or **IA64**
   - architecture of currently running process: **AMD64** or **IA64** or **x86**

   See the Microsoft documentation pages:

   - [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)
   - [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
   - [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys)

On using a batch file to install something it is in general advisable to take the architecture of the Windows operating system into account and not the architecture of the command process executing currently the batch file.

On running a batch file which just calls other applications it is usually advisable to run the application with same architecture as the current process uses which is the reason why value of environment variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` depends on 64-bit Windows also on architecture of current process.

[7-Zip for Windows](https://www.7-zip.org/) is available either as x86 or as x64 application. There is no "x86-64" version as far as I know.

A batch code which could be used is:

```
if /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86"   goto Zip32
if /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "AMD64" goto Zip64
echo ERROR: Processor architecture %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% is not supported.
echo/
pause
goto :EOF

:Zip32
if "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" (
    echo Using 32-bit 7-Zip ...
) else (
    echo Using 32-bit 7-Zip on 64-bit Windows ...
)
rem The commands using 32-bit 7-Zip.
goto :EOF

:Zip64
echo Using 64-bit 7-Zip ...
rem The commands using 64-bit 7-Zip.
```